# Can I still travel today if my Japan visa expires tomorrow?

Tags: visas, japan, filipino-citizens

I will be going today, the 23rd and, my visa expires on the 24th. I'm at the airport right now and they put me on hold!

Answer (score 3):

***Yes***, you can.  A Japanese visa is valid for entry up to and including the day of expiry:

> Visa holders must enter Japan on or before the visa expires, or date of expiry.

http://www.detroit.us.emb-japan.go.jp/pdf/en/tv/explanation.pdf